# Install PostGis on Raspberry Pi from a compiled PostgreSql 9.3 installation

Tags: arm

It took me more than one hour to compile and install PostgreSql 9.3 on Raspberry Pi as as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321858/installation-of-postgreql-9-3-on-raspberry-pi) in the comments.

But I need to enable Geo-spatial extensions from PostGis. While installing Postgis from source, and I'm unable to install extension and I'm asked about postgresql-common and other packages which comes with the default postgresql 9.1 installation with **apt-get**. I really need to use version **9.3** for its *Json* features.

Is there any other way of installing PosGis in Postgresql 9.3 compiled from source ?

Comment: did you get any answer or did you manage to install postgis ?

Comment: Fact is, I managed to compile it for roughly one hour and installed it. But some postgis required extensions weren't linked and i find out I needed to change so many things in the Postgres variables , I just left it there.